# JQuery code not changing CSS

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui, jquery-animate, slider

I have the following snippet of code:

http://jsfiddle.net/Wcexy/

Which reads:

HTML:

`<div id="secrets-slider"></div>`

CSS:

```
#secrets-slider {
    position: relative;
    left: 50%;
    top:50px;
    height: 200px;
}

.ui-state-default, .ui-widget-content .ui-state-default {
    background: red;
}
```

Javascript:

```
var flash = 1;

$(function () {
    $("#secrets-slider").slider({
        orientation: "vertical",
        range: "min",
        min: 0,
        max: 100,
        value: 70,
        animate: 3000,
        slide: function (event, ui) {
            $("#amount").val(ui.value);
            flash=0;        
        },
    });
    function flashing() {
        if (flash === 0) {
            $("#secrets-slider a").stop(true, true);
        } else {
            $("#secrets-slider a").animate(
                {
                    backgroundColor: '#ff8c00'
                }, 1000,
                function() {
                    $("#secrets-slider a").animate(
                        {
                            backgroundColor: '#f00'
                        }, 1000
                    )
                }                                         
            )
            setTimeout(flashing,2000);
        }
    }
    flashing();
});
```

Now I implement this code into a website I am trying to make for a friend.  Available here: http://blah.eu5.org/

When I add this code, it doesn't seem to function.  Noticably, the jquery slider handle doesn't pulse at all.  I have checked that the event is firing with `alert("Moo");` and it is, but it doesn't seem to be altering the CSS.  Why might this be?

Comment: What about that global variable "flash"? Where/how is it defined?

Comment: It's defined at the top of hs.js(the main script file to control the page) as a global variable.  It starts as 1 and moves to 0 when you first move the slider.

Comment: Every time I inspect the document, I don't see the change happening at all.  Is there some CSS overwriting this?  Maybe my CSS reset?

Comment: In short, what could stop `$("#secrets-slider a").animate({backgroundColor:'#ff8c00'}, 1000);` from working?

Comment: Additional: http://jsfiddle.net/Wcexy/1/.  It seems I can get it to resize, it's only color that isn't working.  The resize DOES work when implemented on the site.  This issue is more clearly a CSS problem.  Anyone suggest?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of headaches, I figured out that using `.animate()` on a background is actually part of the JQuery UI plugin, and I was using a minimalised version of the UI plugin which didn't include this code(pretty much had the slider and that was it).

Let that be a lesson to me.